# How can I modify this Binary Search Tree ADT to implement Priority Queue ADT?

Tags: c++, binary-search-tree, priority-queue

Included every file I got just in case, but the BinarySearchTree.h is at the end. I know priority queue needs to queue() which needs an int to give priority, dequeue() which will remove the top data, peek() will show data that was first in (FIFO way), but how will Implement a Priority Queue using this BinarySearchADT? I don't expect a full answer, but at least point me in the right direction.

Edit: Added Prio_Queue ADT that uses the BinarySerachTree.h at the end. Still a bit clueless.

```
#pragma once

#ifndef _BINARY_TREE_INTERFACE 
#define _BINARY_TREE_INTERFACE 
#include "NotFoundException.h"
template< class ItemType>
class BinaryTreeInterface
{
public:

    virtual bool isEmpty() const = 0;
    virtual int getHeight() const = 0;
    virtual int getNumberOfNodes() const = 0;
    virtual ItemType getRootData() const = 0;
    virtual void setRootData(const ItemType& newData) = 0;
    virtual bool add(const ItemType & newData) = 0;
    virtual bool remove(const ItemType & data) = 0;
    virtual void clear() = 0;
    virtual ItemType getEntry(const ItemType & anEntry) const throw(NotFoundException) = 0;
    virtual bool contains(const ItemType & anEntry) const = 0;
    virtual void preorderTraverse(void visit(ItemType&)) const = 0;
    virtual void inorderTraverse(void visit(ItemType&)) const = 0;
    virtual void postorderTraverse(void visit(ItemType&)) const = 0;
}; 
#endif 

#pragma once
#ifndef _BINARY_NODE 
#define _BINARY_NODE 
template< class ItemType>
class BinaryNode
{
private:
    ItemType item;
    BinaryNode<ItemType>* leftChildPtr; 
    BinaryNode<ItemType>* rightChildPtr; 

public:
    BinaryNode();
    BinaryNode(const ItemType& anItem);
    BinaryNode(const ItemType& anItem,
        BinaryNode<ItemType>* leftPtr,
        BinaryNode<ItemType>* rightPtr);
    void setItem(const ItemType& anItem);
    ItemType getItem() const;
    ItemType getCon() const;
    bool isLeaf() const;
    BinaryNode<ItemType>* getLeftChildPtr() const;
    BinaryNode<ItemType>* getRightChildPtr() const;
    void setLeftChildPtr(BinaryNode<ItemType>* leftPtr);
    void setRightChildPtr(BinaryNode<ItemType>* rightPtr);
};
#endif 

template<class ItemType> 
BinaryNode<ItemType>::BinaryNode():item(nullptr), leftChildPtr(nullptr), rightChildPtr(nullptr)
{

}

template<class ItemType>
BinaryNode<ItemType>::BinaryNode(const ItemType& anItem) :item(NULL), leftChildPtr(nullptr), rightChildPtr(nullptr)
{

}

template<class ItemType>
BinaryNode<ItemType>::BinaryNode(const ItemType& anItem, BinaryNode* leftPtr, BinaryNode* rightPtr) :item(anItem), leftChildPtr(nullptr), rightChildPtr(nullptr)
{

}

template<class ItemType>
void BinaryNode<ItemType>::setItem(const ItemType& anItem)
{
    item = anItem;
}

template<class ItemType>
ItemType BinaryNode<ItemType>::getItem() const
{
    return item;
}

template<class ItemType>
ItemType BinaryNode<ItemType>::getCon() const
{
    return con;
}

template<class ItemType>
bool BinaryNode<ItemType>::isLeaf() const
{
    return ((leftChildPtr == nullptr) && (rightChildPtr == nullptr));
}

template<class ItemType>
void BinaryNode<ItemType>::setLeftChildPtr(BinaryNode* leftPtr) 
{
    leftChildPtr = leftPtr;
}

template<class ItemType>
void BinaryNode<ItemType>::setRightChildPtr(BinaryNode* rightPtr)
{
    rightChildPtr = rightPtr;
}

template<class ItemType>
BinaryNode<ItemType>* BinaryNode<ItemType>::getLeftChildPtr() const
{
    return leftChildPtr;
}

template<class ItemType>
BinaryNode<ItemType>* BinaryNode<ItemType>::getRightChildPtr() const
{
    return  rightChildPtr;
}


#pragma once
#ifndef _BINARY_NODE_TREE 
#define _BINARY_NODE_TREE 
#include "BinaryTreeInterface.h" 
#include "BinaryNode.h" 
#include "PrecondViolatedExcep.h" 
#include "NotFoundException.h" 

template< class ItemType>
class BinaryNodeTree : public BinaryTreeInterface<ItemType>
{
private:
 BinaryNode<ItemType>* rootPtr;
protected:
    // Recursive methods
    int getHeightHelper(BinaryNode<ItemType>* subTreePtr) const;
    int getNumberOfNodesHelper(BinaryNode<ItemType>* subTreePtr) const; 
    
    void destroyTree(BinaryNode<ItemType>* subTreePtr);

    BinaryNode<ItemType>* balancedAdd(BinaryNode<ItemType>* subTreePtr, BinaryNode<ItemType>* newNodePtr);
    BinaryNode<ItemType>* removeValue(BinaryNode<ItemType>* subTreePtr, const ItemType target, bool& success);
    BinaryNode<ItemType>* moveValuesUpTree(BinaryNode<ItemType>* subTreePtr);
    BinaryNode<ItemType>* findNode(BinaryNode<ItemType>* treePtr, const ItemType& target, bool& success) const;
    BinaryNode<ItemType>* copyTree(const BinaryNode<ItemType>* treePtr) const;

    
    void preorder(void visit(ItemType&), BinaryNode<ItemType>* treePtr) const;
    void inorder(void visit(ItemType&), BinaryNode<ItemType>* treePtr) const;
    void postorder(void visit(ItemType&), BinaryNode<ItemType>* treePtr) const;
public:
    BinaryNodeTree();
    BinaryNodeTree(const ItemType& rootItem);
    BinaryNodeTree(const ItemType& rootItem, const BinaryNodeTree<ItemType>* leftTreePtr, const BinaryNodeTree<ItemType>* rightTreePtr);
    BinaryNodeTree(const BinaryNodeTree<ItemType>& tree);
    virtual ~BinaryNodeTree();
    
    bool isEmpty() const;
    int getHeight() const;
    int getNumberOfNodes() const;
    ItemType getRootData() const throw(PrecondViolatedExcep);

    void setRootData(const ItemType& newData);

    bool add(const ItemType& newData); 
    bool remove(const ItemType& data); 
    void clear();
    ItemType getEntry(const ItemType& anEntry) const throw(NotFoundException);
    bool contains(const ItemType& anEntry) const;

    void preorderTraverse(void visit(ItemType&)) const;
    void inorderTraverse(void visit(ItemType&)) const;
    void postorderTraverse(void visit(ItemType&)) const;

    BinaryNodeTree& operator=(const BinaryNodeTree& rightHandSide);
}; 
 
#endif 

template<class ItemType>
int BinaryNodeTree<ItemType>::getHeightHelper(BinaryNode<ItemType>* subTreePtr)const
{
    if (subTreePtr == nullptr)
        return 0;
    else
        return 1 + max(getHeightHelper(subTreePtr->getLeftChildPtr()), getHeightHelper(subTreePtr->getRightChildPtr()));
}

template<class ItemType>
int BinaryNodeTree<ItemType>::getNumberOfNodesHelper(BinaryNode<ItemType>* subTreePtr)const
{
    if (subTreePtr == nullptr)
        return 0;
    else
        return 1 + getNumberOfNodesHelper(subTreePtr->getLeftChildPtr())+ getNumberOfNodesHelper(subTreePtr->getRightChildPtr());
}

template<class ItemType>
BinaryNode<ItemType>* BinaryNodeTree<ItemType>::balancedAdd(BinaryNode<ItemType>* subTreePtr, BinaryNode<ItemType>* newNodePtr)
{
    if (subTreePtr == nullptr)
        return newNodePtr;
    else
    {
        BinaryNode<ItemType>* leftPtr = subTreePtr->getLeftChildPtr();
        BinaryNode<ItemType>* rightPtr = subTreePtr->getRightChildPtr();
        if (getHeightHelper(leftPtr) > getHeightHelper(rightPtr))
        {
            rightPtr = balancedAdd(rightPtr, newNodePtr);
            subTreePtr->setRightChildPtr(rightPtr);
        }
        else
        {
            leftPtr = balancedAdd(leftPtr, newNodePtr);
            subTreePtr->setLeftChildPtr(leftPtr);
        }
        return subTreePtr;
    }
}

template<class ItemType>
BinaryNode<ItemType>* BinaryNodeTree<ItemType>::moveValuesUpTree(BinaryNode<ItemType>* subTreePtr)
{
    BinaryNode<ItemType>* leftPtr = subTreePtr->getLeftChildPtr();
    BinaryNode<ItemType>* rightPtr = subTreePtr->getRightChildPtr();
    int leftHeight = getHeightHelper(leftPtr);
    int rightHeight = getHeightHelper(rightPtr);

    if (leftHeight > rightHeight)
    {
        subTreePtr->setItem(leftPtr->getItem());
        leftPtr = moveValuesUpTree(leftPtr);
        subTreePtr->setLeftChildPtr(leftPtr);
        return subTreePtr;
    }
    else
    {
        if (rightPtr != nullptr)
        {
            subTreePtr->setItem(rightPtr->getItem());
            rightPtr = moveValuesUpTree(rightPtr);
            subTreePtr->setRightChildPtr(rightPtr);
            return subTreePtr;
        }
        else
        {
            delete subTreePtr;
            return nullptr;
        }
    }

}

template<class ItemType>
BinaryNode<ItemType>* BinaryNodeTree<ItemType>::removeValue(BinaryNode<ItemType>* subTreePtr, const ItemType target, bool& success)
{
    if (subTreePtr == nullptr)
        return nullptr;
    if (subTreePtr->getItem() == target)
    {
        subTreePtr = moveValuesUpTree(subTreePtr);
        success = true;
        return subTreePtr;
    }
    else
    {
        BinaryNode<ItemType>* targetNodePtr = removeValue(subTreePtr->getLeftChildPtr(), target, success);
        subTreePtr->setLeftChildPtr(targetNodePtr);
        if (!success)
        {
            targetNodePtr = removeValue(subTreePtr->getRightChildPtr(), target, success);
            subTreePtr->setRightChildPtr(targetNodePtr);
        }
        return subTreePtr;
    }
}

template<class ItemType>
BinaryNode<ItemType>* BinaryNodeTree<ItemType>::findNode(BinaryNode<ItemType>* treePtr, const ItemType& target, bool& success) const
{
    if (treePtr == nullptr)
        return nullptr;

    if (treePtr->getItem() == target)
    {
        success = true;
        return treePtr;
    }
    else
    {
        BinaryNode<ItemType>* targetNodePtr = findNode(treePtr->getLeftChildPtr(), target, success);
        if (!success)
        {
            targetNodePtr = findNode(treePtr->getRightChildPtr(), target, success);
        }
        return targetNodePtr;
    }
}

template<class ItemType>
BinaryNode<ItemType>* BinaryNodeTree<ItemType>::copyTree(const BinaryNode<ItemType>* treePtr) const
{
    BinaryNode* newTreePtr = nullptr;

    if (treePtr != nullptr)
    {
        newTreePtr = new BinaryNode(treePtr->getItem(), nullptr, nullptr);
        newTreePtr->setLeftChildPtr(copyTree(treePtr->getLeftChildPtr()));
        newTreePtr->setRightChildPtr(copyTree(treePtr->getRightChildPtr()));
    }
    return newTreePtr;
}

template<class ItemType>
void BinaryNodeTree<ItemType>::destroyTree(BinaryNode<ItemType>* subTreePtr)
{
    if (subTreePtr != nullptr)
    {
        destroyTree(subTreePtr->getLeftChildPtr());
        destroyTree(subTreePtr->getRightChildPtr());
        delete subTreePtr;
    }
}

template<class ItemType>
void BinaryNodeTree<ItemType>::preorder(void visit(ItemType&), BinaryNode<ItemType>* treePtr) const
{
    if (treePtr != nullptr)
    {
        ItemType theItem = treePtr->getItem();
        visit(theItem);
        preorder(visit, treePtr->getLeftChildPtr());
        preorder(visit, treePtr->getRightChildPtr());
    }
}

template<class ItemType>
void BinaryNodeTree<ItemType>::inorder(void visit(ItemType&), BinaryNode<ItemType>* treePtr) const
{
    if (treePtr != nullptr)
    {
        inorder(visit, treePtr->getLeftChildPtr());
        ItemType theItem = treePtr->getItem();
        visit(theItem);
        inorder(visit, treePtr->getRightChildPtr());
    }
}

template<class ItemType>
void BinaryNodeTree<ItemType>::postorder(void visit(ItemType&), BinaryNode<ItemType>* treePtr) const
{
    if (treePtr != nullptr)
    {
        postorder(visit, treePtr->getLeftChildPtr());
        postorder(visit, treePtr->getRightChildPtr());
        ItemType theItem = treePtr->getItem();
        visit(theItem);

    }
}
template<class ItemType>
BinaryNodeTree<ItemType>::BinaryNodeTree() : rootPtr(nullptr)
{

}

template<class ItemType>
BinaryNodeTree<ItemType>::BinaryNodeTree(const ItemType& rootItem) 
{
    rootPtr = new BinaryNode(rootItem, nullptr, nullptr);
}

template<class ItemType>
BinaryNodeTree<ItemType>::BinaryNodeTree(const ItemType& rootItem, const BinaryNodeTree* leftTreePtr, const BinaryNodeTree* rightTreePtr)
{
    rootPtr = new BinaryNode(rootItem, copyTree(leftTreePtr->rootPtr), copyTree(rightTreePtr->rootPtr));
}

template<class ItemType>
BinaryNodeTree<ItemType>::BinaryNodeTree(const BinaryNodeTree& treeItem)
{
    rootPtr = copyTree(treeItem.rootPtr);
}

template<class ItemType>
BinaryNodeTree<ItemType>::~BinaryNodeTree()
{
    destroyTree(rootPtr);
}

template<class ItemType>
bool BinaryNodeTree<ItemType>::isEmpty() const
{
    return rootPtr == nullptr;
}

template<class ItemType>
int BinaryNodeTree<ItemType>::getHeight() const
{
    return getHeightHelper(rootPtr);
}


template<class ItemType>
int BinaryNodeTree<ItemType>::getNumberOfNodes() const
{
    return getNumberOfNodesHelper(rootPtr);
}

template<class ItemType>
void BinaryNodeTree<ItemType>::clear() 
{
    destroyTree(rootPtr);
    rootPtr = nullptr;
}

template<class ItemType>
ItemType BinaryNodeTree<ItemType>::getRootData()const throw (PrecondViolatedExcep)
{
    if (isEmpty())
        throw PrecondViolatedExcep("getRootData() called with empty tree");

    return rootPtr->getItem();
}

//setRootData definition
template<class ItemType>
void BinaryNodeTree<ItemType>::setRootData(const ItemType& newItem)
{
    if (isEmpty())
        rootPtr = new BinaryNode<ItemType>(newItem, nullptr, nullptr);
    else
        rootPtr->setItem(newItem);
}

template<class ItemType>
bool BinaryNodeTree<ItemType>::add(const ItemType& newData)
{
    BinaryNode<ItemType>* newNodePtr = new BinaryNode<ItemType>(newData);
    rootPtr = balancedAdd(rootPtr, newNodePtr);

    return true;
}


template<class ItemType>
bool BinaryNodeTree<ItemType>::remove(const ItemType& target)
{
    bool isSuccessful = false;
    rootPtr = removeValue(rootPtr, target, isSuccessful);

    return isSuccessful;
}

template<class ItemType>
ItemType BinaryNodeTree<ItemType>::getEntry(const ItemType& anEntry) const throw (NotFoundException) 
{
    bool isSuccessful = false;
    BinaryNode<ItemType>* binaryNodePtr = findNode(rootPtr, anEntry, isSuccessful);

    if (isSuccessful)
        return binaryNodePtr->getItem();
    else
        throw PrecondViolatedExcep("Entry Not found in tree");

    
}

template<class ItemType>
bool BinaryNodeTree<ItemType>::contains(const ItemType& anEntry) const
{
    bool isSuccessful = false;
    findNode(rootPtr, anEntry, isSuccessful);
    return isSuccessful;
}

template<class ItemType>
void BinaryNodeTree<ItemType>::preorderTraverse(void visit(ItemType&))const
{

    preorder(visit, rootPtr);
}

template<class ItemType>
void BinaryNodeTree<ItemType>::inorderTraverse(void visit(ItemType&))const
{

    inorder(visit, rootPtr);
}

template<class ItemType>
void BinaryNodeTree<ItemType>::postorderTraverse(void visit(ItemType&))const
{

    postorder(visit, rootPtr);
}

template<class ItemType>
BinaryNodeTree<ItemType>& BinaryNodeTree<ItemType>::operator=(const BinaryNodeTree& rightHandSide)
{
    if (!isEmpty())
        clear();
    this = copyTree(&rightHandSide);

    return *this;
}

#pragma once
#define _NOT_FOUND_EXCEPTION
using namespace std;
#include "PrecondViolatedExcep.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <stdexcept> 
class NotFoundException : public logic_error
{
public:
    NotFoundException(const string& message = "");

};


NotFoundException::NotFoundException(const string& message) : logic_error("Precondition Violated Exception: " + message)
{

}

#pragma once

#ifndef _PRECOND_VIOLATED_EXCEP 
#define _PRECOND_VIOLATED_EXCEP 
#include <stdexcept> 
#include <string> 
using namespace std;
class PrecondViolatedExcep : public logic_error
{
public:
    PrecondViolatedExcep(const string& message = "");
}; 

PrecondViolatedExcep::PrecondViolatedExcep(const string & message) :
    logic_error("Precondition Violated Exception: " + message)
{
} 
#endif 

#pragma once
#ifndef _BINARY_SEARCH_TREE
#define _BINARY_SEARCH_TREE
#include "BinaryTreeInterface.h"
#include "BinaryNodeTree.h"
#include "NotFoundException.h"
#include "PrecondViolatedExcep.h"
template<class ItemType>
class BinarySearchTree : public BinaryNodeTree<ItemType>
{
private:
    BinaryNode<ItemType>* rootPtr;

protected:
    //------------------------------------------------------------
    // Protected Utility Methods Section:
    // Recursive helper methods for the public methods.
    //------------------------------------------------------------
    // Recursively finds where the given node should be placed and
    // inserts it in a leaf at that point.
    BinaryNode<ItemType>* insertInorder(BinaryNode<ItemType>* subTreePtr, BinaryNode<ItemType>* newNode);

    BinaryNode<ItemType>* removeValue(BinaryNode<ItemType>* subTreePtr,const ItemType target,bool& success);

    BinaryNode<ItemType>* removeNode(BinaryNode<ItemType>* nodePtr);

    BinaryNode<ItemType>* removeLeftmostNode(BinaryNode<ItemType>* subTreePtr, ItemType& inorderSuccessor);

    BinaryNode<ItemType>* findNode(BinaryNode<ItemType>* treePtr, const ItemType& target) const;

public:
    //------------------------------------------------------------
    // Constructor and Destructor Section.
    //------------------------------------------------------------
    BinarySearchTree();
    BinarySearchTree(const ItemType& rootItem);
    BinarySearchTree(const BinarySearchTree<ItemType>& tree);
    virtual ~BinarySearchTree();

    //------------------------------------------------------------
    // Public Methods Section.
    //------------------------------------------------------------
    bool isEmpty() const;
    int getHeight() const;
    int getNumberOfNodes() const;
    ItemType getRootData() const throw(PrecondViolatedExcep);
    void setRootData(const ItemType& newData) const throw(PrecondViolatedExcep);
    bool add(const ItemType& newEntry);
    bool remove(const ItemType& anEntry);
    void clear();
    ItemType getEntry(const ItemType& anEntry) const throw(NotFoundException);
    bool contains(const ItemType& anEntry) const;

    //------------------------------------------------------------
    // Public Traversals Section.
    //------------------------------------------------------------
    void preorderTraverse(void visit(ItemType&)) const;
    void inorderTraverse(void visit(ItemType&)) const;
    void postorderTraverse(void visit(ItemType&)) const;
    //------------------------------------------------------------
    // Overloaded Operator Section.
    //------------------------------------------------------------
    BinarySearchTree<ItemType>& operator=(const BinarySearchTree<ItemType>&
        rightHandSide);
}; 
#endif

#include <iostream>

template<class ItemType>
BinaryNode<ItemType>*BinarySearchTree<ItemType>::insertInorder(BinaryNode<ItemType>*subTreePtr, BinaryNode<ItemType>*newNodePtr)
{
    if (subTreePtr == nullptr)
        return newNodePtr;
    else
    {
        if (subTreePtr->getItem() > newNodePtr->getItem())
            subTreePtr->setLeftChildPtr(insertInorder(subTreePtr -> getLeftChildPtr(), newNodePtr));
        else
            subTreePtr->setRightChildPtr(insertInorder(subTreePtr -> getRightChildPtr(), newNodePtr));
        return subTreePtr;
    }
}


template<class ItemType>
BinaryNode<ItemType>*
BinarySearchTree<ItemType>::removeValue(BinaryNode<ItemType>*subTreePtr,
    const ItemType target,
    bool& success)
{
    if (subTreePtr == nullptr)
    {
        success = false;
        return nullptr;
    }
    if (subTreePtr->getItem() == target)
    {
        subTreePtr = removeNode(subTreePtr);
        success = true;
        return subTreePtr;
    }
    else
    {
        if (subTreePtr->getItem() > target)
            subTreePtr->setLeftChildPtr(removeValue(subTreePtr->getLeftChildPtr(), target, success));
        else
            subTreePtr->setRightChildPtr(removeValue(subTreePtr->getRightChildPtr(), target, success));
        return subTreePtr;
    }
}

template<class ItemType>
BinaryNode<ItemType>*
BinarySearchTree<ItemType>::removeNode(BinaryNode<ItemType>* nodePtr)
{
    if (nodePtr->isLeaf())
    {
        delete nodePtr;
        return (nodePtr = nullptr);
    }
    else if (nodePtr->getLeftChildPtr() == nullptr)
    {
        BinaryNode<ItemType>* nodeToConnectPtr = nodePtr->getRightChildPtr();
        delete nodePtr;
        nodePtr = nullptr;
        return nodeToConnectPtr;
    }
    else if (nodePtr->getRightChildPtr() == nullptr)
    {
        BinaryNode<ItemType>* nodeToConnectPtr = nodePtr->getLeftChildPtr();
        delete nodePtr;
        nodePtr = nullptr;
        return nodeToConnectPtr;
    }
    else
    {
        ItemType newNodeValue;
        nodePtr->setRightChildPtr(removeLeftmostNode(nodePtr-> getRightChildPtr(), newNodeValue));
        nodePtr->setItem(newNodeValue);
        return nodePtr;
    }
}

template<class ItemType>
BinaryNode<ItemType>*
BinarySearchTree<ItemType>::removeLeftmostNode(BinaryNode<ItemType>* nodePtr,
    ItemType& inorderSuccessor)
{
    if (nodePtr->getLeftChildPtr() == nullptr)
    {
        inorderSuccessor = nodePtr->getItem();
        return removeNode(nodePtr);
    }
    else
    {
        nodePtr->setLeftChildPtr(removeLeftmostNode(nodePtr-> getLeftChildPtr(), inorderSuccessor));
        return nodePtr;
    }
}

template<class ItemType>
BinaryNode<ItemType>* BinarySearchTree<ItemType>::findNode(BinaryNode<ItemType>*subTreePtr, const ItemType& target) const
{
    if (subTreePtr == nullptr)
        return nullptr;
    else if (subTreePtr->getItem() == target)
        return subTreePtr;
    else if (subTreePtr->getItem() > target)
        return findNode(subTreePtr->getLeftChildPtr(), target);
    else
        return findNode(subTreePtr->getRightChildPtr(), target);
}

template<class ItemType>
BinarySearchTree<ItemType>::BinarySearchTree() : rootPtr(nullptr)
{
} 
template<class ItemType>
BinarySearchTree<ItemType>::BinarySearchTree(const ItemType& rootItem)
{
    rootPtr = new BinaryNode<ItemType>(rootItem, nullptr, nullptr);
}
template<class ItemType>
BinarySearchTree<ItemType>::BinarySearchTree(const BinarySearchTree<ItemType>&
    treePtr)
{
    rootPtr = this->copyTree(treePtr.rootPtr);
} 

template<class ItemType>
BinarySearchTree<ItemType>::~BinarySearchTree()
{
    this->destroyTree(rootPtr);
}

template<class ItemType>
bool BinarySearchTree<ItemType>::isEmpty() const
{
    return rootPtr == nullptr;
}
template<class ItemType>
int BinarySearchTree<ItemType>::getHeight() const
{
    return this->getHeightHelper(rootPtr);
}
template<class ItemType>
int BinarySearchTree<ItemType>::getNumberOfNodes() const
{
    return this->getNumberOfNodesHelper(rootPtr);
}
template<class ItemType>
void BinarySearchTree<ItemType>::clear()
{
    this->destroyTree(rootPtr);
    rootPtr = nullptr;
}
template<class ItemType>
ItemType BinarySearchTree<ItemType>::getRootData() const
throw(PrecondViolatedExcep)
{
    if (isEmpty())
        throw PrecondViolatedExcep("getRootData() called with empty tree.");
    return rootPtr->getItem();
}
template<class ItemType>
bool BinarySearchTree<ItemType>::add(const ItemType& newData)
{
    BinaryNode<ItemType>* newNodePtr = new BinaryNode<ItemType>(newData);
    rootPtr = insertInorder(rootPtr, newNodePtr);
    return true;
}
template<class ItemType>
bool BinarySearchTree<ItemType>::remove(const ItemType& target)
{
    bool isSuccessful = false;
    rootPtr = removeValue(rootPtr, target, isSuccessful);
    return isSuccessful;
}

template<class ItemType>
ItemType BinarySearchTree<ItemType>::getEntry(const ItemType& anEntry) const
throw(NotFoundException)
{
    BinaryNode<ItemType>* nodeWithEntry = findNode(rootPtr, anEntry);
    if (nodeWithEntry == nullptr)
        throw NotFoundException("Entry not found in tree.");
    else
        return nodeWithEntry->getItem();
}

template<class ItemType>
bool BinarySearchTree<ItemType>::contains(const ItemType& anEntry) const
{
    return findNode(rootPtr, anEntry);
}

template<class ItemType>
void BinarySearchTree<ItemType>::preorderTraverse(void visit(ItemType&)) const
{
    this->preorder(visit, rootPtr);
} 

template<class ItemType>
void BinarySearchTree<ItemType>::inorderTraverse(void visit(ItemType&)) const
{
    this->inorder(visit, rootPtr);
} 

template<class ItemType>
void BinarySearchTree<ItemType>::postorderTraverse(void visit(ItemType&)) const
{
    this->postorder(visit, rootPtr);
} 


template<class ItemType>
BinarySearchTree<ItemType>& BinarySearchTree<ItemType>::
operator=(const BinarySearchTree<ItemType>& rightHandSide)
{
    if (!isEmpty())
        clear();
    this = copyTree(&rightHandSide);
    return *this;
} 

#pragma
#include "BinarySearchTree.h"


template<class ItemType>
class Prio_Queue : public BinarySearchTree<ItemType>
{
    BinarySearchTree<ItemType> BST;

public:
    Prio_Queue();
    void Enqueue(ItemType);
    void Dequeue(ItemType);
    void Peek();
};

template<class ItemType>
Prio_Queue<ItemType>::Prio_Queue()
{
}

template<class ItemType>
void Prio_Queue<ItemType>::Enqueue(ItemType entry)
{
    if (BST.isEmpty())
    {
        BST.setRootData(entry);
    }
    else
        BST.add(entry);
}

template<class ItemType>
void Prio_Queue<ItemType>::Dequeue(ItemType entry)
{
    BST.remove(entry);
}

template<class ItemType>
void Prio_Queue<ItemType>::Peek()
{
    cout << BST.getRootData();
}
```

Comment: Priority Queues are normally implemented with min-heaps, not with binary search trees. It's more efficient.

Comment: I read that, but Im tasked to do it with binary search trees

Comment: Before you write a single line of code, you should have a design.  Code is not a design.  On paper, how would you accomplish this?  Pretend C++ does not exist.  Now whatever you implemented on paper, you translate that to C++.

Comment: All code in your question is not relevant to the question.